# Use Distributed Cache - HIVE STREAMING

Tags: ruby, hadoop, streaming, hive, distributed-cache

I would like to zip the files of a Ruby gem, and distribute them to my EMR cluster.  I would also like to use a simple Ruby script that references the files in this this gem in a Hive Streaming job.

I add both the file and the archive to the Hadoop Distributed Cache using:

```
ADD FILE /home/user/mobile.rb; 
ADD ARCHIVE /home/user/browser-master.zip;
```

Inside mobile.rb, I am using the code below to simulate using the gem:

```
$.push File.expand_path("../browser-master/lib", __FILE__)
require "browser"
```

When I have the unzipped archive and the mobile.rb file in the same dir on my local machine, I can stream data to it and run the program just fine.

But when I add the files to my Hadoop cluster I get this error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask. An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
```

Does my mobile.rb need to point to something else when the archive is unzipped in the Distributed Cache?

I am using Hive 0.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing, adding the entire directory (unzipped) using `ADD FILE` seemed to work:

```
ADD FILE /home/user/browser-master
```

Comment: Just an update, I have been using this approach with Ruby and Python and it has been working great.